# I would like to add more custom batch widget, so how to set custom html helpers to the JHtml class

Tags: modal, batch

I know I will have to update the model $batch_commands array and also add the new methods/commands I want to run beyond the normal. But this questions main focus is to add more fields/widgets the batch modal like those in the abstract class JHtmlBatch. So I can use `<?php echo JHtml::_('batch.customfield'); ?>` in the default_batch.php file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I found the way that this can be done. In the helpers folder of you component you create a new folder called html and in it you place your file. Now using `<?php echo JHtml::_('widget.customfield'); ?>` as our example the file name will be admin/helpers/html/**widget.php** then in the file you add the following:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Content HTML helper
 *
 * @since  3.0
 */
abstract class JHtmlWidget
{
    public static function customfield()
    {
        $html = '<h1>works</h1>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Then update this file views/customviewname/tmpl/default.php by adding the following php

```
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/html');
```

Then in the html area you can now declare the widget simply with the following

`<?php echo JHtml::_('widget.customfield'); ?>`

have fun...